# Why python software package does not run under WSL2?

Tags: python, ubuntu, error-handling, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tcpserver

I wanted to use WSL2 Ubuntu to run some scientific programs on my PC (Phenix package). It used to work previously on wsl but after recent update to wsl2 one of the programs written in Python has some problems:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/f/cryoEM/phenix-1.18rc4-3812/build/../modules/phenix/wxGUI2/command_line/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/mnt/f/cryoEM/phenix-1.18rc4-3812/build/../modules/phenix/wxGUI2/command_line/main.py", line 16, in run
    from wxGUI2 import App
  File "/mnt/f/cryoEM/phenix-1.18rc4-3812/modules/phenix/wxGUI2/App.py", line 7, in <module>
    from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
  File "/mnt/f/cryoEM/phenix-1.18rc4-3812/conda_base/lib/python2.7/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 105, in <module>
    import BaseHTTPServer
  File "/mnt/f/cryoEM/phenix-1.18rc4-3812/conda_base/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 102, in <module>
    class HTTPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TCPServer'
```

I have checked all the packages (BaseHTTPServer, SocketServer) and everything seems to be fine. Using python provided with the package and importing modules separately also works without errors. My previous computer also with WSL2 was running this software package without any issues. I believe that there is something missing on the wsl2 Ubuntu level but cannot guess what it is. Do you have any suggestions what I could try to do? Thanks!

Comment: Clone or move the project in WSL user home folder.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much! Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know about this case but the solution I provided is coming from since the begining of WSL.